# Apex safe navigation operator chaining

Tags: apex, exception

I'm a little bit confused. Let's say we have a code

```
String[] recordTypes = AppConfigData__c.getValues('dummy')?.value__c.split('\\s*;\\s*');
```

Why it works even if `getValues()` returns `null`? Why  `split` doesn't throw an exception?

Updated:

```
String s;
String[] res = s?.toUppercase().split(';');
System.debug(res);
```

debug returns `null` without any exceptions although `s` is `null` (`toUppercase` as well)

Did I miss something?

Comment: Whats confusing to you? This operator is designed to short circuit the expression of the left hand side of the evaluates to null. See [Use the Safe Navigation Operator to Avoid Null Pointer Exceptions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm&type=5&release=228).

Comment: why split doesn't throw an exception? (it really doesn't)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Safe navigator `?.` checks if the value, to which it is applied **is not** `null`, only in this condition the next call is performed. If the left-hand-side of the chain expression evaluates to `null`, the right-hand-side isn’t evaluated

```
a?.b // Evaluates to: a == null ? null : a.b
```

---

In order, to understand better safe navigator, we can rewrite the current code to the following (they are equivalent):

**Ternary operator**

```
String[] recordTypes
    = AppConfigData__c.getValues('dummy') == null ? null
        : AppConfigData__c.getValues('dummy').value__c.split('\\s*;\\s*');
```

**if condition**

```
String[] recordTypes = null;
if(AppConfigData__c.getValues('dummy') != null){
    recordTypes = AppConfigData__c.getValues('dummy').value__c.split('\\s*;\\s*')
}
```

---

you can read more details and see more examples in documentation [Safe Navigation Operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm)

---

I recommend you add one more safe navigator before splitting a string because the stored field in the custom setting could be `null` as well.

```
String[] recordTypes = AppConfigData__c.getValues('dummy')?.value__c?.split('\\s*;\\s*');
if(recordTypes != null) {
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: I updated the question. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually according to documentation - `If the left-hand-side of the chain expression evaluates to null, the right-hand-side isn’t evaluated. ` So there is no need to implement additional ?. operators

Comment: @pincet if you want to have an exception thrown, don't use a safe navigator. Safe navigator is specifically designed to go from exception handling to check for nulls.